# UIScrollView in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement something that looks like the current natwest app.

[image]

It needs to be a `UITableViewController`, with a `UIView` at the top that can scroll through numerous different screens.

Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option which may be suitable is to use a UIViewController (with the tableView delegate methods) and create the UIView and the UITableView and add them to the UIViewController. This way you can potentially still make use of UITableView headers in the tableView.

Also, the view at the top will remain static when scrolling the tableView

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
// Create your view here

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 380)];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:topView];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

To scroll the topView you'll need to add a UIScrollView etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just add both UIScrollView and UITableVIew in Your UIViewController[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIScrollView and place it as the TableViewHeader.

All the delegates and logics of the UIScrollView can be written in a separate class which is different the UITableViewController class.

Answer (score -1):

It looks fairly simple. That scroll view bit look like either a `tableViewHeader` or a section `header`.

Just create a custom view with a scroll view in it and then set it as the tableview header.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is literally all that is needed. The actual interface is really simple to create.